# How to deploy HTML code on free cloud platform?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, deployment

I build an application (written in HTML, JQuery, CSS) in Visual studio code on my desktop. I want to deploy it to the free cloud platform. I tried AWS of Amazon and created a GIT repository. But they ask to do it with the React app., not with visual studio. I did not succeed. There is another way to do it, directly with Visual Studio Code? Should I install the React app. and rewrite the code?

Comment: If it is AWS's policy, then you may need to follow their requirements (as it is a free platform). Of course you may choose switching to another free platform which accept VS codes , or stay to use AWS service and use React.

Comment: You may create a linux instance and configure apache or node server

Comment: Have you checked [Google Cloud Free Tire](https://cloud.google.com/free)? For example you can use `f1-micro` VM instance with linux for your application for free.

Comment: See full workflow how to do it for Google App Engine here - https://worklifenotes.com/2020/05/24/google-app-engine-github-actions-static-websites/